# VS Code: Autocomplete in Debug Console only works with Tab, not Enter

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I can't figure out how to make the autocomplete work with Enter in the Debug Console. It's pretty annoying because it's working in the code windows but not in the Debug Console (only Tab autocomplete works there).

Maybe there are some settings I can tweak?

PLEEEEASE HELP it's annoying like a HELL.

Comment: I was going to do the same but then I realized that in some situations is annoying to set the enter as autocomplete as you will autocomplete instead of submitting

Comment: @Ignasi I didn't face such use case and using tab instead of enter is a VERY, SUPER annoying bug that I can't get rid off.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

VS Code now has a setting for that: Debug › Console: Accept Suggestion On Enter.

Comment: YEEES! YEES! YES!

Comment: It turned out the problem with this setting was it wasn't where I expected it. I found it in the "Features" then "Debug". Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the Debug: Console setting on my VSCode. I found another called

> acceptSelectedSuggestionOnEnter

but I couldn't assign the key "Enter" to it (it's a known bug in the IDE, I think). So I had to do this by adding the following keyboard shortcut to my keybindings.json file (Cmd-Shift-P -> Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)):

```
{
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestionOnEnter"
    "when": "suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
},
```